# Relative stability of keto- enol form of acetyl chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

Why is the keto form of acetyl chloride more stable even though the enol form is stabilized by the hydrogen bonding?

Comment: The enol form of acetyl chloride isn't stabilized by hydrogen bonding. Can you include a picture of what you mean?

Comment: The enol form is stabilised more than or comparable to ketones in phenol and 1,3 or 2,4 type diketones.

Answer (score 1):

The stability of keto-enol compounds depends on the solution they are present in.

Keto compounds are stabilized due to inter-molecular hydrogen bonding when present in a polar solvent (for example water).

Enol compounds are stable when present in non-polar solvents, in which intra-molecular hydrogen bonding stabilizes them.